# sql select returns "\u0000" instead of bit value of 0?

Tags: mysql, select, alter

I'm trying to run a SQL select query and needed to add another row for boolean values to track the notifications that users clicked, so I ran this query to create the column:

```
ALTER TABLE Notifications ADD clicked BIT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;
```

However, once I ran the select query in python, the column I added returns this value:

```
"clicked": "\u0000"
```

How do I get the result to look like this:

```
 "clicked": 0
```

I know I can cast the result to turn it into 0, but I want the select to return 0

Comment: You might be better off using a small int value rather than BIT, especially if they can be 'clicked' more than once

Comment: @Grantly Unless you just want to know if it is clicked, and don't care how often.

Comment: Yeah I agree @Ivar, just sometimes I skip using BIT fields just because they are PITA :)

Comment: I guess, this is JSON problem. Try classic code.

Comment: I dont really know python or mysql.  In the jdbc driver it's returned as a Boolean.  Look here for documentation on types in the python connector: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-fieldtype.html .  I would imagine that you can provide a custom converter for a type.

Comment: @Grantly I think small int would work. It won't be used as a count, but the select would return a number instead of a string. Thanks!